# S3 optimized writer not working when dynamic partition overwrite is enabled

Tags: apache-spark

In AWS EMR 5.29 (Spark 2.4), setting `spark.sql.parquet.fs.optimized.committer.optimization-enabled`
 to `true` results in a direct write to a desired folder/bucket.

When setting `spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode` to `dynamic`, Spark writes to a staging folder first, then rewrites to the set destination, as if the first setting is not set to `true`.

Is this a known issue or am i missing something to enforce the first config to work together with the second

Comment: Did you find answer to your question?